# Multiple conditions in if/else statement?

Tags: c++

I'm still a beginner so I apologize if these questions are asked frequently. I've done several searches but I can't find an adequate answer. Here are my two main questions:

I'm building a simple counting program that allows users to count by 1's, 2's, 3's etc. First off, here's the code for my function:

```
int Count::numOne() {

cout << "You chose to count by 1! Press \"Y\" to continue counting. Press \"N\" to return to the main page." << endl;

while (cin >> yesNo) {
    if ((yesNo == 'y') || (yesNo == 'Y')) {
        ++one;
        cout << one << endl;

    }
    else if ((yesNo == 'n') || (yesNo == 'N')) {
        cout << "User selected no." << endl; //How do I return back to the main function?
}
    else {
        cout << "Please enter either \"Y\" or \"N\"." << endl;
    }

}

return 0;
}
```

1. I've gotten the program to function correctly for the most part, but is there "better" or cleaner syntax to use for the if/else conditions? I feel that

   ```
   if ((yesNo == 'y') || (yesNo == 'Y'))
   ```

   has unnecessary redundancy and could be cleaner.
2. Also, if a user enters 'n' or 'N', how can I return back to the main function and start the program from the beginning?

Comment: For single-character comparisons like this you could alternatively use a switch block with cases for each option.

Comment: use a std::tolower function to compare two characters then  if you want to start again from the begininng use a loop or a goto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like:

```
string yes {"Yy"};

cout << "You chose to count by 1! Press \"Y\" to continue counting. Press \"N\" to return to the main page." << endl;

while (cin >> yesNo) {
    if (yes.find_first_of(yesNo) != string::npos) {
        ++one;
        cout << one << endl;

    }
    // ... other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Doing both comparisons is just fine from a compiled code perspective, and calling out each comparison clearly is very readable

2) What you want is a `break;` expression to break out of your while loop

Answer (score 0):

1. Parentheses around `operator==` call are unnecessary in this case, see [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Unless you feel like making a custom comparison function and using that, that's all there is to it. That function could be like this:

   ```
   #include <cctype>

   // will accept both c and option as lowercase or uppercase
   bool isOption(char c, char option)
   {
       return std::tolower(c) == std::tolower(option);
   }
   ```
2. Just `break` out of the loop, so it `return`s `0`, or `return` (possibly other) value, since you're in a function.

Comment: Why not just `return std::tolower(c) == std::tolower(option);`?

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary, but still recommended for style, since it makes the author's intent more obvious to the reader and relieves the reader of having to correctly remember operator precedence rules when examining the code.